# Anisble: How to create as gcp VM with custom resources?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, ansible-awx

I am able to change VMs configuration on GCP with machine type as "e2-medium", "e2-small"..etc. this machine type comes with fixed vcpu and RAM, but I need custom resources.

However, my requirement is to change the VMs RAM or CPU to a custom value. Like 10vcpu with 24gb ram or anything. below is the part of my code where I am changing the machine type. is there any way to select type as custom and choose my own values for CPU and ram.

```
  - name: Update the Machine Type 
    gcp_compute_instance:
      name: "{{instance_name}}"
      project: "{{ project_id }}"
      zone: "{{zone}}"
      machine_type: "{{machine_type}}"
      labels:
        environment: testing
      auth_kind: serviceaccount
      service_account_file: "{{ credentials_file }}"
      status: RUNNING
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A machine type with custom resources can have this form : "e2-custom-10-24576"  for your requirement of 10vCPU and 24GB of RAM.

You can have more details in this documentation : https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/general-purpose-machines#custom_machine_types